# Creating A new class in CSS that applies to HTML You have no access to

Tags: html, css, frontend

I was wondering is it possible to add a new class using CSS to HTML you dont have access to?
I am working with a survey programme and i can only create custom CSS but i need to separate two divs by giving them different classes.
I know this is obviously possible but Is this possible in CSS without access to the HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add classes to html with css. What you can do is select elements you want to style not by class but by type name in combination with parent containers types if needed.

Comment: "but by tags" — Do you mean with *type selectors*? That won't work. The question says that both elements are divs. They have the same type.

Comment: Sure, but with that amount of information provided it's hard to tell how exactly the divs are ment to be styled or what is html structure of the document, it might be possible to be done by using type selectors that are specific enough.

Comment: No, it isn't. You can't get more specific than `div` with a type selector.

Comment: Can't you do that by including the divs parent in the selector?

Comment: So now you are talking about using descendant or child combinators AND type selectors rather than just type selectors.

Comment: That was what I ment from the begining, thanks for noticing, it in fact might have been unclear. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can only add a class to a document by:

- Editing the class attribute in the HTML source code
- Using DOM to manipulate the classes on an element (e.g. via `setAttribute`, `className` or `classList`).

---

Try to find [a selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-selectors-3-20180130/) that uniquely matches the element in question without adding additional classes to the document.